# OCB implementation issiues

Tags: c, security, encryption, ocb-mode

I tried out reference implementation of OCB algorithm http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/news/code/ocb_ref.c and after adding print out of decrypted data there is a missing element.

Due to the size of code I posted in on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/sbNUpzmN

the main function

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #define PLAIN_SIZE 8
  int main() {
    uint8_t zeroes[PLAIN_SIZE];
    uint8_t nonce[12] = {0,};
    uint8_t p[PLAIN_SIZE+8] = {0,};
    uint8_t final[16];
    uint8_t *c;
    unsigned i, next;
    int result;
    for (i=0; i<(PLAIN_SIZE); i++) {
        zeroes[i]=2;
        p[i]=5;
        }
    p[i+8]=5;
    printf("Nonece: %d\n",NONCEBYTES);
    /* Encrypt and output RFC vector */
    c = malloc(22400);
    next = 0;
    for (i=0; i<PLAIN_SIZE; i++) {
        nonce[10] = i;
        ocb_encrypt(c+next, zeroes, nonce, zeroes, i, zeroes, i);
        next = next + i + TAGBYTES;
        ocb_encrypt(c+next, zeroes, nonce, zeroes, 0, zeroes, i);
        next = next + i + TAGBYTES;
        ocb_encrypt(c+next, zeroes, nonce, zeroes, i, zeroes, 0);
        next = next + TAGBYTES;
    }
    nonce[10] = 0;
    ocb_encrypt(final, zeroes, nonce, c, next, zeroes, 0);
    if (NONCEBYTES == 12) {
        printf("AEAD_AES_%d_OCB_TAGLEN%d Output: ", KEYBYTES*8, TAGBYTES*8);
        for (i=0; i<TAGBYTES; i++) printf("%02X", final[i]);  printf("\n");
    }

    /* Decrypt and test for all zeros and authenticity */
    result = ocb_decrypt(p, zeroes, nonce, c, next, final, TAGBYTES);
    if (result) { printf("FAIL\n"); return 0; }
    next = 0;
    for (i=0; i<PLAIN_SIZE; i++) {
        nonce[10] = i;
        result = ocb_decrypt(p, zeroes, nonce, zeroes, i, c+next, i+TAGBYTES);
        if (result || memcmp(p,zeroes,i)) { printf("FAIL\n"); return 0; }
        next = next + i + TAGBYTES;
        result = ocb_decrypt(p, zeroes, nonce, zeroes, 0, c+next, i+TAGBYTES);
        if (result || memcmp(p,zeroes,i)) { printf("FAIL\n"); return 0; }
        next = next + i + TAGBYTES;
        result = ocb_decrypt(p, zeroes, nonce, zeroes, i, c+next, TAGBYTES);
        if (result || memcmp(p,zeroes,i)) { printf("FAIL\n"); return 0; }
        next = next + TAGBYTES;
    }
    for (i=0; i<(PLAIN_SIZE); i++) printf("%d",  zeroes[i]); printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<(PLAIN_SIZE); i++) printf("%d", p[i]); printf("\n");
    free(c);


    return 0;
}
```

the output yields

```
->gcc  -W -g -lcrypto ocb_rev.c && ./a.out
Nonece: 12
AEAD_AES_128_OCB_TAGLEN128 Output: 0DA35760F29E327625FBC0071E18E330
22222222
22222225
```

Hence the last element of the array have not been written, but the authentication have passed.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with the code:\

1. the function `ocb_encrypt()` needs the appropriate header file #included.
2. variable `result` not used
3. variable `p` set but not used.

Given the above problems with the code

1. either the OP had warnings turned off during the compile or ignored them
2. the compiler will (due to no prototype for `ocb_encrypt()`)

   - assume the inputs are all integer
   - assume the returned value, if any, is integer

The compiler assumptions for `ocb_encrypt()` are probably the main reason
the output is not correct.

If the compiler warnings were all enabled and then corrected, resulting in a clean compile, then the problem would be debugable, as it is, it is anybodys guess what the compiler passed to `ocb_encrypt()` and how the `ocb_encrypt()` function reacted to being passed the wrong type of parameters

Comment: what are you talking about? what include? did you actually read what I wrote? 

"Due to the size of code I posted in on pastebin http://pastebin.com/sbNUpzmN" there is no need for prototype when function is declared in the same file above the main. 

You also see the compilation flag in my post "gcc  -W -g -lcrypto ocb_rev.c && ./a.out" so I have not turned of any warning.

p is used .... how about you actually pay attention to the post before trolling?